# How to add soap header using node-soap or strong-soap in node.js

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, strongloop, node-soap

I'm trying to use an xml web service soap client in node and I'm not sure how to add the soap header for my example.

Looking at strong-soap, there is a method `addSoapHeader(value, qname, options)` but I'm not sure what I need to pass in as qname and options in this case.

My request that I need to send

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://schemas.foo.com/webservices/authentication" xmlns:hot="http://foo.com/webservices/hotelv3" xmlns:hot1="http://schemas.foo.com/webservices/hotelv3">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <aut:AuthenticationHeader>
         <aut:LoginName>foo</aut:LoginName>
         <aut:Password>secret</aut:Password>
         <aut:Culture>en_US</aut:Culture>
         <aut:Version>7.123</aut:Version>
      </aut:AuthenticationHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hot:BookHotelV3>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <hot:request>
            <hot1:RecordLocatorId>0</hot1:RecordLocatorId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hot1:RoomsInfo>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <hot1:RoomReserveInfo>
                  <hot1:RoomId>123</hot1:RoomId>
                  <hot1:ContactPassenger>
                     <hot1:FirstName>Joe</hot1:FirstName>
                     <hot1:LastName>Doe</hot1:LastName>
                  </hot1:ContactPassenger>
                  <hot1:AdultNum>2</hot1:AdultNum>
                  <hot1:ChildNum>0</hot1:ChildNum>
               </hot1:RoomReserveInfo>
            </hot1:RoomsInfo>
            <hot1:PaymentType>Obligo</hot1:PaymentType>
         </hot:request>
      </hot:BookHotelV3>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Should value be:

```
value = { LoginName:'foo', Password:'secret', Culture:'en_US', Version:7.123 }
```

Then what should qname be? `auth:AuthenticationHeader`?  Where do I specify the namespace?

Is there an easier example with node-soap?  Should I use strong-soap or node-soap?

Answer (score 9):

I found the way to do that by reading through the codebase. (**strong-soap**)

qname - qualified name

for simple headers

```
const QName = require('strong-soap').QName;

client.addSoapHeader({
    item: {
        key: 'api_key',
        value: apiKey
    }
}, new QName(nsURI, 'Auth'));
```

for complex headers like you have, specify it in xml directly

```
client.addSoapHeader(
    `<aut:Auth xmlns:aut="${nsURI}">
        <aut:LoginName>foo</aut:LoginName>
    </aut:Auth>`
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else comes here looking for answers:

```
const QName = require('strong-soap').QName;
client.addSoapHeader(
  {
    $value: {
      LoginName: 'foo',
      Password: 'secret',
      Culture: 'en_US',
      Version: '7.123',
    },
  },
  new QName(
    'http://schemas.foo.com/webservices/authentication',
    'AuthenticationHeader',
  )
);
```

Comment: Hi! Please elaborate your code